# Using T-SQL, how can I list the columns of two tables and indicate whether or not the columns are indexed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, `customers` and `orders`.

I would like a query to list all the columns from customers and orders and list whether or not the columns are indexed.

I am assuming I need to make use of `sys.columns` and `sys.indexes` but cannot understand how to create the proper query.

**Customer** table:

```
CustomerId (primary key, clustered index)
Name
Address
PostalCode (non-unique, non-clustered index)
```

**Orders** table:

```
OrderId (primary key, clustered index)
CustomerId  (non-unique, non-clustered index)
Description
CompanyId (non-unique, non-clustered index)
```

Query results should look like:

```
 column name |  indexed 
-------------+------------
  CustomerId | true
        Name | false
     Address | false
  PostalCode | true
     OrderId | true
  CustomerId | true
 Description | false
   CompanyId | true
```

Comment: By "has index", do you want to identify the columns that are indexed as single columns, or as participating in any index, or all of the above?

Comment: Thanks, all of the above would be good. I updated the query results to 'indexed'

Comment: What if they are the first or second column of a multi-column index, what about `include` columns, what about columnstore indexes, xml indexes? Please be specific

Comment: Aside: A list of non-unique column names without the corresponding table names doesn't seem very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bare simplest solution to get you a true/false indicator would be as follows to check if the table's column is referenced in `sys.index_columns`. This doesn't differentiate between the index type, included column etc but you can easily extrapolate that if required.

```
select c.name ColumnName,
    case 
        when exists (select * from sys.index_columns ic where ic.object_id=c.object_id and ic.column_id=c.column_id)
        then 'true' else 'false'
    end Indexed
from sys.tables t
  join sys.columns c on c.object_id=t.object_id
where t.name='TableName'
```

Note, you have to use `exists` here as joining will likely result in duplicates since each column can participate in any number of indexes.

Answer (score 1):

`sys.columns` contains all the columns on a given object and `sys.index_columns` contains all the columns in an index, so something like this should get you started:

```
SELECT c.name, CASE WHEN ic.column_id IS NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END AS isIndexed
FROM sys.columns c
LEFT JOIN sys.index_columns ic
    ON c.object_id = ic.object_id
    AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.customers')
```